# kendo TreeList: sort columns based on parent element only?

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-treeview

Here is an [example kendo treeList](http://dojo.telerik.com/akAwe/9). How can i sort the data in the treeList, depending on values based only on parent element?

In the example, if i sort the data on column 'P names', the child elements are also sorted. How can i sort only parent elements?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add custom comparer for column.

Look in [kendo Docs](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.sortable.compare)

In your case it will look like this:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    sortable: true,
    columns: [{
        field: "item",
        sortable: {
            compare: function(a, b) {
                if(a.level>1){
                         var dataRows = $scope.grid.items();
                         var ARowIndex = dataRows.index(a);
                         var BRowIndex = dataRows.index(b);
                         return ARowIndex > BRowIndex ;
                         }
                         else
                            return a.item> b.item;
                }
            }
        }]
    });
```

Comment: Is there a way to have a single compare function for all columns? I need to sort only the parent elements with default sorting provided by kendo. For child elements- no sorting required.